# Detect the closure of an eclipse rcp application with taskkill

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, listener, rcp

I'm working on an eclipse rcp application and here is my question:

I have a WorkbenchWindowAdvisor with the method preWindowShellClose() (I know this method is called when somebody try to close the application) and this method displays a small window asking the user if he really wants to close the application ...

This is pretty standard but sometimes i need to close the application by a command line (without access to the interface), for example:
taskkill /IM example.exe

So with this command line the small window asking "Are you really sure..." appears and i don't want that! (I don't want to force the closure with something like that neither: taskkill /F /IM example.exe)

So I would like to detect if the application is being closed by pressing the "close window" button or by a taskkill.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like using java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Thread t) should help you execute your code before JVM instance is killed.

Comment: The problem is that the hook is executed after preWindowShellClose() and also in the two following cases:
-When the application is closed by a taskkill
-When the application is closed by the "close window" button.

So i can't do what i want with this function :/